# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [conf/admin/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security, but for some reason my web.xml isn't finding my applicationContext.xml
web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
            classpath:conf/admin/applicationContext.xml
            classpath:conf/admin/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

My applicationContext.xml is in myProject/conf/admin/applicationContext.xml, in the same place as my web.xml but it always throws the exception:

```
    14:18:07,793 ERROR [ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [conf/admin/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [conf/admin/applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I've tried putting inside the WEB-INF folder ( like every Spring Security tutorial does ) which is in myProject/dist/web/WEB-INF, but when I clean my project to refresh and rebuild it gets deleted.

So what am I doing wrong? Putting the wrong path in `contextConfigLocation` or applicationContext.xml in the wrong place?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are following the [Standard Maven Directory Structure](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) i.e. your XML config files are under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/conf/admin` then try this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/conf/admin/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/conf/admin/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Another approach is to go with the defaults:

1. Just place you `applicationContext.xml` file under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` and it will be picked up by spring by default.
2. You can then add this `<import resource="applicationContext-security.xml" />` line in your applicationContext.xml to import Security config.
3. Check this [Repository](https://github.com/RawSanj/spring-tiles-sample-app) using default config approach.

Comment: @StudioWorks please accept this solution if this answers your question.